# Converting ASCII to uint8

Tags: c, ascii, printf, uint

I need to send some number sequences to a microcontroller. Here is my function:

```
void DriveForward()
{       
      printf("137 0 0 128 0");          
}
```

The micro does not accept ASCII while my function sends as ASCII. I need to send that ASCII string as `uint8`. Any idea how can I do the conversion?

In this case, `printf` does not print on screen but it directly sends to serial port. And its the only command that sends to serial port, so I need to do some conversion beforehand.

Comment: ASCII is a text encoding. `uint8` is not. It's a data type. You will have to tell us what text encoding the controller expects.

Comment: Have you looked at atoi()? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Do you mean that instead of the characters "137", you want to pass a character (byte) with a value of 137? If so, you can't use `printf()` because it will stop at the first character with a value of zero.

Comment: You cannot embed zeros into a string, and expect it to be printed through `printf`. You need to go character-by-character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be confused by your question, but you can try something like (just for this case to test):

```
  printf("%c%c%c%c%c", 137, 0, 0, 128, 0);
```

This will send four characters encoded in ASCII with the numerical values you put afterwards.

Also, most technical documentation that tells you that you should use `uint8` is refering that you send to the cable a full 8-bit value (speaking of characters here or ASCII then does not apply. They're just values of 8 bits that can be represented using an `unit8`).

How this is usually done is by using some low-level functions such as `write`, that can send an buffer of `uint8`, so, if you have to send that values, you can have a buffer like this:

```
uint8 send_buffer[] = {137, 0, 0, 128, 0};
```

and then:

```
write (send_buffer, 5, output_file_or_serial_conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your  function, try receiving with `scanf`, it's the inverse of `printf`, so if your code looks something like this:

```
printf("%i %i %i", value1, value2, value3);
```

Then receive it with something like this:

```
char value1, value2, value3;
sscanf(received_string, "%i %i %i", &value1, &value2, &value3);
```

**edit**:
2 years later, I revisit this answer, I'm not so sure `scanf` is the inverse of `printf`.
I'm not deleting this answer for historical reasons.